# Making This "Fancy" Sort Algorithm a Little Better

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, sorting

This is my code:

```py
def add_to_destination_array(destination_arr, src1, iSrc1, src2, iSrc2):
    temp_array_length = len(destination_arr)
    while len(destination_arr) - temp_array_length < len(src1) + len(src2):
        if iSrc1 < len(src1):
            if iSrc2 == len(src2):
                destination_arr.append(src1[iSrc1])
                iSrc1 += 1
            else:
                if src1[iSrc1] <= src2[iSrc2]:
                    destination_arr.append(src1[iSrc1])
                    iSrc1 += 1
                elif src2[iSrc2] <= src1[iSrc1]:
                    destination_arr.append(src2[iSrc2])
                    iSrc2 += 1
        elif iSrc2 < len(src2):
            if iSrc1 == len(src1):
                destination_arr.append(src2[iSrc2])
                iSrc2 += 1
            else:
                if src2[iSrc2] <= src1[iSrc1]:
                    destination_arr.append(src2[iSrc2])
                    iSrc2 += 1
                elif src1[iSrc1] <= src2[iSrc2]:
                    destination_arr.append(src1[iSrc1])
                    iSrc1 += 1


def fancy_sort(array_to_sort):
    destination_array = []
    source1 = [array_to_sort[0]]
    source2 = []
    iSource1 = 0
    iSource2 = 0
    got_first_sublist = False
    first_sublist_start = 0
    second_sublist_start = 0
    array_sorted = False

    for i in range(1, len(array_to_sort)):
        if len(source1) == 0:
            source1.append(array_to_sort[i])
            first_sublist_start = i
        elif not got_first_sublist:
            if source1[i-first_sublist_start-1] <= array_to_sort[i]:
                # Add elements to the first sublist
                source1.append(array_to_sort[i])
            else:
                # First sublist found, now we start finding the seconds sublist
                source2.append(array_to_sort[i])
                second_sublist_start = i
                got_first_sublist = True
        else:
            if source2[i-second_sublist_start-1] <= array_to_sort[i]:
                # Add elements to the second sublist
                source2.append(array_to_sort[i])
            else:
                # Start adding elements to the destination_array
                add_to_destination_array(destination_array, source1, iSource1, source2, iSource2)
                
                # Reset the variables and start over
                first_sublist_start = i
                source1 = [array_to_sort[i]]
                source2 = []
                iSource1 = 0
                iSource2 = 0
                got_first_sublist = False
    
    # If it didn't completely finish "sorting"
    if len(source1) > 0:
        if len(source1) == len(array_to_sort):
            array_sorted = True
        elif len(source2) > 0:
            add_to_destination_array(destination_array, source1, iSource1, source2, iSource2)
        else:
            for i in source1:
                destination_array.append(i)
    
    # Call the function again to continue sorting
    if not array_sorted:
        return fancy_sort(destination_array)
    return array_to_sort

sorting_array = [31, 72, 32, 10, 95, 50, 25, 18]


print(f"Before: {sorting_array}")

sorted_array = fancy_sort(sorting_array)

print(f"After:  {sorted_array}")
```

I know it's not the best, but it still works. This algorithm is supposed to be similar to the merge sort, but it doesn't really split the array, and then merges them together. This algorith is supposed to find two already sorted sub-arrays (or sub-lists if you want to call it that), and then "merge" them into another array (called the destination array).

Here is the info I was given to make create this algorithm:

> **Algorithm in Plain English**
> A teacher is trying to alphabetize a collection of papers. She picks up the papers in her hand and, starting at the top of her stack, works her way down until she finds the first paper out of order. That sub-stack is sorted, and is set aside. She does the same thing to find the next sorted sub-stack. These two sub-stacks are then combined into a single sorted stack that she places on the table. She continues through the original stack in her hand, combining pairs of sorted sub-stacks and putting the results on top of the stack on the table. When she is finished, only the stack on the table remains. Now she picks up the stack on the table and again searches for sorted sub-stacks. When she finds a pair of these, they are combined and placed on the table again. This process continues until again all the papers are on the table. When she picks the stack up off of the table and everything is sorted (there is only one sorted sub-stack), then she is done!
>
> **Detailed Description of the Algorithm**
> Start at the beginning of the array and continue until you discover the first element that is not in sorted order. This sub-array may consist of one element, or it may consist of hundreds. We will call this sub-array source1. Now, starting in the slot after source1, find the next sub-array. Again, this may consist of one element or hundreds. We will call this sub-array source2. Note that source1 and source2 are sorted individually. These two sub-arrays correspond to the small piles in the previous paragraph.
>
> Now we will combine these two sub-arrays to form a single sorted sub-array. We will not do this in place. Instead, we will move them into a new sub-array called destination. Now since the two source arrays are sorted, we can assume that the smallest element in the two arrays is at the beginning of one of the two source arrays. In other words, it is at source1[0] or source2[0]. Therefore destination[0] must be filled with either source1[0] or source2[0]. If, for example, source2 has the lower of the two elements, then that element is moved to destination and the index of source2 (which we will call iSource2) is incremented by one. This process is continued until each element from source1 and source2 is moved into destination.
>
> Once the first two sorted sub-arrays are moved to the destination array, then the next two sub-arrays are identified and combined into the destination array. This process continues until each element in the source array is moved into the destination array. Here, we can say that we have completed one pass of the source array.
>
> Note that the sort is not finished yet. We have not sorted the array when we have completed just one pass. The only thing that a single pass accomplishes is to double the size of the sorted sub-arrays. We have to do many passes until the entire destination array becomes a single sorted sub-array. At that point, we can say that the array is sorted.
>
> [image]

I am really wanting to go down to just using the `array_to_sort` and `destination_array` and then just use the indices for the other stuff instead of the two different source arrays.

[Here](https://repl.it/@CodedGenius/MySortingAlgorithm) is a working example.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Leaving "runs" intact during *merge sort* has been called [natural](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort).